# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libsoundtouch.so" not found

Tags: java, android, macos, android-ndk

I am trying to integrate soundtouch library android.

I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libsoundtouch.so" not found
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1077)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:998)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1661)
    at com.ola.soundtouch.SoundTouch.<clinit>(SoundTouch.java:8)
```

This is my directory:

```
:app

:soundtouch

 - jni
 - libs
    - armeabi-v7a
       - libsoundtouch.so
    - arm64-v8a
       - libsoundtouch.so
 - src
    - main
       - jniLibs
         - armeabi-v7a
           - libsoundtouch.so
         - arm64-v8a
           - libsoundtouch.so
```

Using `ndk-build` command I created the `.so` files.

This is my soundtouch `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libsoundtouch.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libsoundtouch.so'
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ["src/main/jniLibs"]
        }
    }
    namespace 'com.example.soundtouch'
    compileSdkVersion 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.soundtouch"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.so"])
    implementation files('libs/armeabi-v7a/libsoundtouch.so')
}
```

In `:app build.gradle` I have added `implementation project(':soundtouch')`

Gradle:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
```

Api Version:

```
Compile 33
Target 33
```

I built the APK but on analyzing it I found in libs folder this doesnt contain the `libsoundtouch.so` file.